# Troubleshooting process for modules which break depending on theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme-fallback

I'm struggling with a module (Sphinx Search Ultimate by Mirasvit) I've installed using the Intenso theme.

I can see the module works fine in RWD (a default Magento theme). In Intenso, I can see the Magento block isn't overwritten with the Mirasvit block code.

As a more general question, how can I better troubleshoot theme-specific problems like this, with extensions I install? Is it most likely that the problem is that a block doesn't exist in the layout of the current theme?

I've tried Alan Storm's "CommerceBug" module, but I still can't find what to modify in the theme to make it work "same as RWD".

Comment: (A) where's the Mirasvit template placed, which theme/package is it in? (B) what's the fallback default package for the Intenso theme? Is it RWD?

Comment: A) switching to RWD and turning template hints on I see the template should be ./design/frontend/base/default/template/mst_searchautocomplete/amazon.phtml B) Intenso's fallback appears to be frontend/base/default (I'm seeing that by turning on template hints and seeing the non-Intenso templates which are used).

Comment: I can also see app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mst_searchautocomplete.xml is what references amazon.phtml, and using CommerceBug, I can see the layout is actually being used. So what would prevent that block from appearing?

Comment: It's really hard to say. Try adding a random echo into the mirasvit template file and searching for it in your pages rendered source code. Without seeing your DB and code structure it's hard to say.